# why spring config server client failed get config from config server?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I set up a local spring boot config server with a gitlab as the config remote. It worked fine. And I set up a config server client web app and it can successfully connect to this config server and get the configs from git repro through this config server. But now I want to do integration tests to my config server and I moved the client web app to the test directory of the config server, and I modify the client's spring.application.config.name to "configserver-tes" so the client web app will not read the default application.yml in the main classpath and read bootstrap.yml in the test class path. In this case, both two web applications could start with different context and ports. Question is the client web app could not read configs from the config server. Could you guys tell my how can I resolve this issue? Or how can I debug it. Thanks.

error log:

```
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 DEBUG jndi [main] Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@dffa30b
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 DEBUG jndi [main] Looking up name="SPRINGCLOUDCONFIGSERVERBOOTSTRAP"
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 DEBUG o.s.j.JndiPropertySource [main] JNDI lookup for name [SPRINGCLOUDCONFIGSERVERBOOTSTRAP] threw NamingException with message: null. Returning null.
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 TRACE o.s.b.a.c.OnPropertyCondition [main] Condition OnPropertyCondition on org.springframework.cloud.config.server.bootstrap.ConfigServerBootstrapConfiguration$LocalPropertySourceLocatorConfiguration did not match due to @ConditionalOnProperty missing required properties spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
2016-09-22 16:49:06,521 DEBUG o.s.c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor [main] Failed to class-load type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:47) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1802) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:642) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:621) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:593) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:750) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:328) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:168) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:140) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at com.yrd.configserver.test.ConfigserverClient.main(ConfigserverClient.java:30) [test-classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:?]
2016-09-22 16:49:06,542 TRACE o.s.b.a.c.OnClassCondition [main] Condition OnClassCondition on org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration$RetryConfiguration did not match due to required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable,org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
2016-09-22 16:49:06,543 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
2016-09-22 16:49:06,559 TRACE o.s.b.a.c.OnClassCondition [main] Condition OnClassCondition on org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration matched due to @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor
2016-09-22 16:49:06,559 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
2016-09-22 16:49:06,570 TRACE o.s.b.a.c.OnClassCondition [main] Condition OnClassCondition on org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$VanillaEncryptionConfiguration did not match due to required @ConditionalOnMissing classes found: org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor
2016-09-22 16:49:06,570 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
2016-09-22 16:49:06,570 TRACE o.s.b.a.c.OnClassCondition [main] Condition OnClassCondition on org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$RsaEncryptionConfiguration matched due to @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor
2016-09-22 16:49:06,571 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
2016-09-22 16:49:06,571 TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver [main] getProperty("encrypt.keyStore.location", String)
2016-09-22 16:49:06,571 DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver [main] Searching for key 'encrypt.keyStore.location' in [bootstrap]
2016-09-22 16:49:06,571 DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver [main] Searching for key 'encrypt.keyStore.location' in [servletConfigInitParams]
2016-09-22 16:49:06,571 DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver [main] Searching for key 'encrypt.keyStore.location' in [servletContextInitParams]
2016-09-22 16:49:06,571 DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver [main] Searching for key 'encrypt.keyStore.location' in [jndiProperties]
2016-09-22 16:49:06,571 DEBUG o.s.j.JndiTemplate [main] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/encrypt.keyStore.location]
2016-09-22 16:49:06,571 DEBUG jndi [main] InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
2016-09-22 16:49:06,571 DEBUG jndi [main] Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@f8f56b9
] not found - trying original name [SPRINGCLOUDCONFIGSERVERBOOTSTRAP]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env/SPR
INGCLOUDCONFIGSERVERBOOTSTRAP'
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 DEBUG o.s.j.JndiTemplate [main] Looking up JNDI object with name [SPRINGCLOUDCONFIGSERVERBOOTSTRAP]
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 DEBUG jndi [main] InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 DEBUG jndi [main] Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localC
ontextRoot@dffa30b
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 DEBUG jndi [main] Looking up name="SPRINGCLOUDCONFIGSERVERBOOTSTRAP"
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 DEBUG o.s.j.JndiPropertySource [main] JNDI lookup for name [SPRINGCLOUDCONFIGSERVERBOOTSTRAP] threw Naming
Exception with message: null. Returning null.
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 TRACE o.s.b.a.c.OnPropertyCondition [main] Condition OnPropertyCondition on org.springframework.cloud.conf
ig.server.bootstrap.ConfigServerBootstrapConfiguration$LocalPropertySourceLocatorConfiguration did not match due to @ConditionalOn
Property missing required properties spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap
2016-09-22 16:49:06,477 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigu
rationReport'
2016-09-22 16:49:06,521 DEBUG o.s.c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor [main] Failed to class-load type while reading annotati
on metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesV
isitor.java:47) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1802) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RE
LEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:642) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64) [spring-core-4.2.6
.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.ja
va:98) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.
java:102) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.ja
va:93) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:621) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:593) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:750) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:328) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:168) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:140) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at com.yrd.configserver.test.ConfigserverClient.main(ConfigserverClient.java:30) [test-classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:?]
2016-09-22 16:49:06,542 TRACE o.s.b.a.c.OnClassCondition [main] Condition OnClassCondition on org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration$RetryConfiguration did not match due to required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable,org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
2016-09-22 16:49:06,543 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
```

Comment: The error says `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry` which is optional. Can you provide a sample project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @spencergibb test worked the second day. I still didn't figure out why, because I didn't change anything about the project and codes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @leo , i think  you are missing one of the spring boot jar

Answer (score 0):

I get this block resolved somehow. Here is my test class and bootstrap.yml.

```java
package com.yrd.configserver.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * This is a embedded spring boot web application for integration test.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ConfigserverClient {

  static {
    System.setProperty("spring.cloud.config.enabled", "true");
  }

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

  public static void main(final String... args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ConfigserverClient.class, args);
  }


  /**
   * This method is a way to get the specific configuration from the web application.
   * @param propertyName: property name of the configuration.
   * @return
   */
  @RequestMapping("/show")
  public String getPropertyByName(final @RequestParam String propertyName) {
    return environment.getProperty(propertyName);
  }
}
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      discovery:
        enabled: false

      profile: env_${ENV:development}

      label: master
      uri: http://user:user_pass@localhost:8888

  application:
    name: configserver-test
  config:
    name: configserver-test  # This config is to stop the client web app to read the application.yml in the path.

security.basic.enabled: false
management.security.enabled: false
server.port: ${app.port:8080}
```